# Matlab construct of classdef with constraints

Tags: matlab, class, oop, methods, encapsulation

I have this

```
classdef what

properties ( ... )
  ...
end

methods (Access=public) 
  ...
end

methods    
  function obj = what(...) ... end % constructor   
  function test = Test1() ... end    
  function test = Test2() ... end
end
```

The constructor has a lot of constraints in it such that when I create the `what` it fails if the conditions are not met, the constraints are tested by calling `Test1` and `Test2`.

I have stored the test functions also under methods, and I want these to be hidden so that they don't show up outside the `classdef`. but I get thrown an error for `Test1` and `Test2`.

I want these `Test` functions to be `private`, `hidden`, and only related to this class but I also want it to be call-able when using the constructor function found in methods, My question is: **what would be the 'correct' place and method to store these functions**.

I am currently getting an error when I use the constructor function, however, if I add the functions in the bottom of the page outside the classdef then the functions work but I am not sure if this is good practice and why I can't have the test functions in the method section.

Comment: Could you please post actual code (minimal code to reproduce the error)? It is hard to know why you would get errors without seeing your code or error messages. See [mcve].

Comment: Also, yes, it is fine to define private functions outside the `classdef` section. But there is no reason why you couldn’t define these as private member functions.

Comment: But if I define these test functions as private member function, would the constructor function be able to call the test functions?

Comment: I don’t see why not. Private member functions are accessible from all member functions, I don’t see why they wouldn’t be accessible from the constructor.

Comment: Please post an example `classdef` file that demonstrates the error you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to deal with this.

1. In general, private functions are placed inside a `methods (Access = private)` block. Sometimes they can also be made static, if this makes sense. Private methods can also be placed in [a separate folder](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/organizing-classes-in-folders.html#br5wlnh).

   ```
   classdef what

   methods % no properties here
     function obj = what(varargin) % constructor
       ...
       out = obj.Test1(in); % object method calling example
       ...
     end
   end

   methods (Access = private)
     function tf = Test1(varargin)
       ...
     end

     % etc ...
   end
   ```
2. If these functions are only ever used by the constructor, you can make them [nested](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html):

   ```
   classdef what

   methods % no properties here
     function obj = what(varargin) % constructor
       ...
       out = Test1(in); % no need for "obj" here
       ...

         function tf = Test1(varargin)
           ...
         end % Test1
     end % constructor
   end % methods
   ```
3. As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921007/matlab-construct-of-classdef-with-constraints/52924195?noredirect=1#comment92758122_52924195) by Cris, you can also put functions after the `classdef` block:

   ```
   classdef what
   ...
   end

   function tf = Test1(varargin)

   end
   ```

The suggestions above should solve your problem. Now for some other comments:

1. It's probably not a goot idea to name your class `what`, as this is a name of a [builtin MATLAB function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/what.html).
2. While it is possible to set a `private` method block to be [`Hidden`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-attributes.html), this is generally not needed in order to "hide" `private` methods, as these are not visible outside the class anyway.
3. I would personally suggest sticking to a certain [naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)) (e.g. [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Pascal,_Modula-2_and_Oberon) or [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java)) (this is referring to the class name which is lowercase as opposed to the "Test" methods which are uppercase).
4. If you're fairly new to MATLAB OOP, you might want to read about [Handle Classes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html).

Comment: You could add a 3rd method: file-level private functions (outside the `classef` block).

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm unfamiliar with this approach, though I suppose I'm not surprised it's possible (and I have to add that I wouldn't like it if I saw a file like that). Any idea in which release this syntax was introduced? Is there any use case you can think of where this approach is better than private functions?

Comment: This is the same thing as private functions in any other M-file. I have quite a few functions like this in a large class I built. They're not class methods because they don't use any of the class data, they just compute something needed in multiple class methods. If these functions made sense for other uses, I would have made them regular function M-files. Another alternative is M-files within a `private` sub-directory.

Comment: This is great stuff, would you mind explaining why I have to have the test function as a nested function inside the construct function(what) and why I can’t have it just as an additional function within methods. I know I should not use what, I just used a arbitrary name as it is the idea I am wondering about.

Comment: @ALEXANDER Making `Test` nested is just one approach. You _can_ have it as another function in a `methods` block, as I showed in the 1st way. You should keep in mind that if you use the _same_ block, it will be exposed (i.e. not hidden) externally, which is not what you wanted - so the solution is to create another block with `private` access. Maybe I misunderstood what you're asking. I can clarify in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/chatlab-and-talktave) if this still isn't clear.

Comment: Okay but what is the logic for obj.Test1 I don't understand why obj. Is required before calling test1 ?

Comment: This is basic OOP: you need an object of a class if you want to call non-static methods.

Comment: Thank you that's great:)